# Obfuscation of Apk>>Application crashes after splash screen

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard

I am Facing problem to obfuscate my android App.My application have 3 Modules.
i enabled proguard in my app using android studio.

**My gradle.build file is below:-**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.scconline"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 14
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                  'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
compile project(':library')
 // compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2'
  compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/fastjson.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-   dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlworker-5.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4-sources.jar')

 }
```

**My proguard rule file is below:-**

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
 -verbose
  -keepattributes *Annotation*

  -keep public class com.scconline.**

  -dontnote com.itextpdf.**
  -dontnote org.mockito.**
  -dontwarn com.itextpdf.**
   -dontwarn org.mockito.**
  -dontwarn android.**
  -dontwarn android.support.**
   -keep class android.support.** { *; }
  -keep interface android.support.** { *; }
  -keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
  -keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
   -dontwarn android.support.design.*
 -dontwarn org.objenesis.**

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
 }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  }

 -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
  public void *(android.view.View);
  public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
  }

  -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  static ** CREATOR;
  }

  -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
 }

  -keepclassmembers class * {
  @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
  }
```

i use above rule file in my main module and rest two module use default rule file, i enable proguard in rest to module also.

Please help!! i would be highly obliged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used below code in my proguard rule file. It will resolve my problem.

```
 -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-ignorewarnings
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
 -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity


-keep public class * extends com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep public class com.scconline.response.**
-keepclassmembers public class com.scconline.response.**{
<init>(...);
*;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static ** CREATOR;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
    -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.properties,**.gif,**.jpg,**.png,**.xml
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,**.xml
-dontwarn android.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.design.*
-dontwarn org.objenesis.**
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 5
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: i want to on proguard..your answer would off the proguard.Thanks for answering.